# Rotating a image by an angle

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a scalar field(2D/3D) varying between 0 and 1. This is aligned at a known angle(\theta). To acheive the rotation of the field knowing the angle, I have tried crudely to rotate it inthe opposite sense. Following is the code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nx = 100
Ny = 100
theta = np.pi/6.

image = 1.0*np.zeros((Nx,Ny))
#Creating a dummy field -> Square
sizex = Nx/5
sizey = Ny/5
for i in range(int(Nx/2.-sizex/2.),int(Nx/2.+sizex/2.)):
    for j in range(int(Ny/2.-sizey/2.),int(Ny/2.+sizey/2.)):
        image[i,j]=1.0

rot_mat = 1.0*np.zeros((2,2))
rot_mat[0,0]=np.cos(theta)
rot_mat[0,1]=-np.sin(theta)
rot_mat[1,0]=np.sin(theta)
rot_mat[1,1]=np.cos(theta)

rot_image = 1.0*np.zeros((Nx,Ny))
rot_centre_x = Nx/2
rot_centre_y = Ny/2
for i in range(0,Nx):
    for j in range(0,Ny):
        rot_x = (i-rot_centre_x)*rot_mat[0,0]+(j-rot_centre_y)*rot_mat[0,1] + rot_centre_x
        rot_y = (i-rot_centre_x)*rot_mat[1,0]+(j-rot_centre_y)*rot_mat[1,1] + rot_centre_y
        if rot_x<Nx-1 and rot_x>0 and rot_y<Ny-1 and rot_y>0:
            rot_image[i,j] = image[int(rot_x),int(rot_y)]

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)
ax1.imshow(image)
ax1.set_title('Before')
ax2.imshow(rot_image)
ax2.set_title('After')
plt.show()
```

This is the result I was able to get.
[image]

Is there any way I can improve this?

**SOLVED**
Using @Mstaino's answer

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [scipy.ndimage.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)

```
rot_image = spimg.rotate(image,theta, reshape=False, order=1)
```

You can tweak the parameters to suit your rotation interpolation. Hope it works

[image]

Comment: I've never tried three axes, but according to the documentation it is possible, since what you are doing is an array transformation. Simply specify the two axes parallel to the plane of rotation using `axes=(i, j)`